# Rails activerecord returning wrong results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rails-activerecord

I am developing a simple rails app and I have a custom method that returns the last created column details

```
def getid
    @b_id = params[:bid]
    @log_id = Log.where("bid = ?",@b_id).last.to_json
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html{render :text => @log_id}
        format.json{render :json => @log_id}
    end
end
```

The column runs the following query in the backend

```
Log Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `logs`.* FROM `logs` WHERE (bid = 'B01') ORDER BY `logs`.`logid` DESC LIMIT 1
```

The corresponding column values are id:3, logid:20002

The json returned is {u'id' : u'20002, u'logid' : u'20002'}

My questions:

1. Why is rails adding `u` to every JSON element?
2. Why is id returned as 20002 instead of 3? (id is auto increment and is a unique key, logid is primary key)

EDIT:

I found out that the character `u` is being added on the python side, as they are unicode strings and got rid of it as shown here

Comment: I am using python requests to get the json

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call `to_json` on the object in this line

```
@log_id = Log.where("bid = ?",@b_id).last.to_json
```

Just the original object is okay.

```
@log_id = Log.where("bid = ?",@b_id).last
```

Because when you call `render json: @obj` there will be an action to convert the obj to json. No need duplication.

Comment: I got rid of the to_json method but I still get the id as 20002 instead of 3(id is rails generated internal id column)